# What kind of pointers can I use when throwing an exception?

Tags: c++, exception

```
struct except
{
    except( const char * key )
        : m_key( key )
    {
    }

    const char * key() { return m_str; }


private:
    const char * m_str;
};

void throwing_function( const std::string & param )
{
    throw except( param.c_str() );
}
```

Consider this snippet: would a call to the member function `key()` of the exception be valid if issued from the scope of the `catch` block?

Comment: I think your real question is "when does the destructor of this string run?"  The question is, will the string be valid once your run up the call stack.  You can't possibly answer that question within the context of your function, so bad idea.

Comment: I wouldn't do this as it is too prone to error. Not what you want when handling errors!

Comment: @NeilKirk What you don't want an error prone error handler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what `param` is a reference to. If it is a reference to a string that is either global, lives higher up the stack then your `catch`, or was dynamically allocated and not destroyed from stack unwinding, it will work, otherwise the string will have been destructed by the time you `catch`.

So, if it wasn't explicit from that explanation: don't do this.